# The rule to have "ing" in the middle of a phrase

Tags: gerunds

I am seeing this pattern in mostly formal sentences and curious what is the rule to write verb+ing after the first part of sentence. Is it replacement for "which"?

"Make possible epidemiological studies and other research endeavors in terms of problems,
having all the data on any given problem immediately available."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a supplementary instruction in this case. It could be written *...in terms of problems, **and have** all the data...*. However using *having* emphasises the need to have the data available at the same time as you are carrying out the studies.

You find the same construction using other verbs, for instance

"Drive carefully paying attention to the actions of other road users" and

"Whisk the milk into the batter a little at a time, being careful not to make the mixture sloppy"

Comment: Thanks! Is it a same for this one?  "High speed rails allows the commuter to leave the driving to the professionals controlling the train, allowing them to get some work done while getting to work safely."

Comment: @AliDay That's not the same, in that case 'driving' is a noun and the 'the driving' is the object of 'leave'. The example could be written "High speed rail allows the commuter to rely on the professionals to drive the train...". What would be similar would be "High speed rail allows the passengers to get some work done relying on the professionals to drive the train". Do you understand the difference?

Comment: sorry I think I was not clear there, I meant the use of "allowing" at last sentence. Also I find another one today which uses "resulting": carbohydrates contains rich elements, resulting in obesity for people who eats foods like pasta regularly.

Comment: @AliDay I see what you mean but I still don't think it's quite the same. In these cases the -ing verb is used to indicate _a consequence_ of the first part of the sentence. You could write "High speed rail allows ... _which means that passengers can_ get some work done..." and in the second case "...contains rich elements _which means that_ people who eat pasta regularly become obese". The initial quote says that the person has to carry out both actions simultaneously.